# How to debug Amazon S3 lifecycle rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I wonder if I'm missing something related to object size.  I have a lifecycle rule set to transition all objects in the bucket to Glacier Deep after 0 days.  However, more than 24 hours later, my objects are still in the Standard class:

```
➜  ~ aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket fms-glacier-lifecycle-test
{
    "Contents": [
        {
            "Key": "20200804 workout routine.xlsx",
            "LastModified": "2021-08-27T03:46:11+00:00",
            "ETag": "\"7a69e57e8f4d38f21dcc13311579c16a\"",
            "Size": 14128,
            "StorageClass": "STANDARD"
        },
        {
            "Key": "empires.txt",
            "LastModified": "2021-08-26T06:52:32+00:00",
            "ETag": "\"5bcfd281af93b72d2245e6759d56bb44\"",
            "Size": 2194,
            "StorageClass": "STANDARD"
        },
        {
            "Key": "package-lock.json.xz",
            "LastModified": "2021-08-26T06:55:02+00:00",
            "ETag": "\"d0a7f5b09a6be8a2517a300c79a335b2\"",
            "Size": 64456,
            "StorageClass": "STANDARD"
        }
    ]
}
```

The [docs say that](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-lifecycle-rule-glacier-storage/) "Amazon S3 Lifecycle configuration rules run once a day at midnight UTC."  As you can see here, I uploaded before midnight UTC but the rules still don't seem to have taken effect.  I know these particular small objects are small, but my goal is to get a SnowCone and have the objects moved to Glacier Deep as soon as possible.  I can't find anything in the docs that suggests size limits or anything else I'm doing wrong.  Is there a log or something that will tell me why my rule didn't apply?  Is there maybe something wrong with the prefix?  [image: AWS console screenshot of lifecycle rule]

Comment: What do you see in AWS Web console gui under properties of one of these object? and Do you see anything in the events logs, if it is enabled?

Comment: GUI shows the same thing- all objects are still standard class.  Is there something else you wanted me to check for?  I just turned on CloudTrail for read/write events- not sure if that will pick up a transition or not.  I did find a related FAQ which indicated that transition rules can take up to 48 hours to take effect, and I'm supposing then it would run at midnight UTC after that- but we are past that deadline and it still hasn't transitioned.

Comment: Did waiting longer resolve the issue? I was able to successfully automatically transition objects from Standard to Deep Archive but had to wait for 3 days after the version action was meant to have happened before the change in storage class occurred. I haven't been able to find any documentation that explains why Deep Archive takes longer (e.g. nothing mentioned here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-transition-general-considerations.html#lifecycle-general-considerations-transition-sc)

Comment: Sorry for delay in response- yes; the apparent issue is that it can take 48 hours for the rule to take effect, and then it may not be processed for an additional 24 hours after that.  I submitted a patch to AWS docs, which they refused, citing that they "didn't have an SLA".  I can't fix stupid, sorry.